# How to type an hooks factory based on factory parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

In Typescript, is it possible to make a factory that return a function that as a name based on the factory parameter that is fully typed ?

Something like this :

```
    type ReturnType<T extends string> = {
      [key in `use${T}`]: () => void;
    };
    
    const hookFactory = <T extends string>(name: string): ReturnType<T> => { // Need to pass "name" value
      const hookName = `use${name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)}`;
    
      return {
        [hookName]: () => {
          console.log("working")
        }
      };
    
    }
```

And use it like this :

```
const { useTest } = hookFactory('test');
```

The example is working, but not typed. I have to guess the hook name is the object deconstruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this :

```
type FactoryReturnType<T extends string> = {
  [key in `use${Capitalize<T>}`]: () => void;
};

function hookFactory<T extends string>(name: T): FactoryReturnType<T> {
  const hookName = `use${name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)}`;

  return {
    [hookName]: () => {
      console.log("working")
    }
  } as FactoryReturnType<T>;
}

const { useTest } = hookFactory('test'); // OK
const { useTest } = hookFactory('testx'); // not OK
```

Comment: Ah, I thought Capitalize capitalized everything passed in, not just the first character. Yeah, that makes my `FirstLetterOf` and infering unnecessary. But I'd suggest avoiding `any` (which completely disables type-checking) - make type assertions as early as you can so that TS can parse what follows without ignoring errors. Add on to `const hookName = ``use${name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)}`;`` a type assertion so you don't have to use `as any` when returning the object at the bottom (you'll also be able to omit the return annotation at the beginning of the function)

Comment: I have updated my answer by using `as FactoryReturnType<T>` instead of `any`. i've tried to remove the type assertion on the return but instead used it on the hookName with `as `use${Capitalize<T>}`` but it didn't worked. Is that what you meant ?

The error :

const hookName: `use${Capitalize<T>}`
Type '{ [x: string]: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'FactoryReturnType<T>'